# hangs after install of PV drivers

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, virtualization, xen, migration

After installing the 32-bit PV drivers (0.97.4) on a 32-bit Windows Server 2003
SP2 guest, the system will hang and/or BSOD on subsequent reboots.

Version-Release number of selected component (if applicable):
dom0: RHEL 5.3 x86_64
domU: Windows 2003 Server SP2 (32-bit)
xenpv-win-32-bit-0.97.4-3.el5

How reproducible: always

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Create win2k3 guest
2. Install PV drivers
3. Reboot
4. Configure PV NIC driver
5. Reboot

Actual results:

System will hang immediately after login on final reboot

Expected results:

No hang

Additional info:

I've found that if I apply all the latest patches to Win2k3 after guest OS
install that instead of a hang I get a BSOD. If I do not install the latest
patches it simply hangs (totally unresponsive to all user input).

If I do not install the PV drivers, everything works fine. I can reboot
multiple times with no issues. As I'm only utilizing the PV NIC in my
configuration, my assumption is that the issue is with the PV NIC driver.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probablt with the PV disk controller driver. If you installed windows using generic IDE/SCSI, changing the controller type to PV will make the VM BSOD on boot.

The VM should have been installed with the PV drivers slipstreamed into the windows installation CD